# Where was the son of the Israelite supposed to go?

Tags: parashas-emor

At the end of Parashat Emor is the story of the “son of the Israelite” who blasphemied HaShem’s name because HaShem returned His judgement to Moshe that the man did not have a right to set up camp with the tribe of Dan, as he would wish, since his father was an Egyptian. Where, then, was he supposed to set up camp, and why?

Comment: You ask four questions here. Please edit to focus on a single question that people can answer.

Comment: "... _because HaShem returned His judgement to Moshe that the man did not have a right to set up camp with the tribe of Dan, as he would wish, since his father was an Egyptian_". This information is not in the verses themselves. They only say that a son of an Israelite woman and an Egyptian man went out and quarreled with an Israelite man, pronounced the [Divine] Name and cursed, and mention his mother's lineage. How do you know the rest of it?

Comment: "_where was he supposed to live if he was being rejected everywhere?_" (1) You only mention he was rejected by the tribe of Dan. How do you know everybody else rejected him? (2) He could have lived outside the tribal encampments, presumably where the _'Erev Rav_ lived. It may not have been dignified, but it would have been living.

Comment: Where did the eiruv rav lived. I suppose he should have lived with them.

Comment: He like the eirev rav was a *member* of Bnai Yisrael as a *convert* just like everyone else who had been at the revelation on Hra Sinai. However, since his father had not been one of the tribes, he did not belong to any tribe. Thus he was supposed to live with those who were not members of a tribe. @LeeN. Note that the definition of a *Jew* is one whose mother is Jewish back to the revelation at Har Sinai. This means that everyone who was at the revelation was *Jewish* including the eirev rav. The members of the tribes were based on the fathers membership back to the original sons of Yaakov.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where did the converts camp in the desert?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37787/where-did-the-converts-camp-in-the-desert)

Comment: @sabbahillel as the question now stands your comment is an answer, would you mind adding it as such?

Comment: @JoshK OK added as an answer

Comment: Why didnt you consider  my previous comment (THE SAME AS HIS) to his as an answer.

Comment: @interested because he explained the reasoning behind the answer such that someone who hadn't previously learned this halacha could understand. It's not the slightest bit personal, your comment was absolutely correct

Comment: @JoshK It is ok I dont mind anyone repeating anything I say or quote in a comment, even as an answer. I am the opposite only 'gratified' by  it. If anything I find this answer very simple and not needing even a link which I usually provide.

Comment: Related: "[What tribe did someone belong to if they didn't have a Jewish father](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59311/1368)"?

Answer (score 2):

He like the *eirev rav* was a member of Klal Yisrael as a convert just like everyone else who had been at the revelation on Har Sinai. However, since his father had not been one of the tribes, he did not belong to any tribe. Thus he was supposed to live with those who were not members of a tribe. Note that the definition of a Jew is one whose mother is Jewish back to the revelation at Har Sinai. This means that everyone who was at the revelation was Jewish including the *eirev rav*. The members of the tribes were based on the fathers membership back to the original sons of Yaakov.